# How to outline a defect in an image?

Tags: image-processing, filters

The images given below are a result of fruit defect detection algorithm i have made myself...

**Just wanted to know is there a way of outlining these defects?**

Original image 1:

[image]

1st Image:

[image]

Original image 2:

[image]
2nd Image:

[image]

What i want to achieve is this :

1. [image]        =>      2. [image]

Comment: You should add more detail, such as, what are the original two images, what operations have you executed on them to obtain this end result, and what is the defect you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, original images would help. Also, what qualifies as a *defect*?

Comment: Check the edit :)

Comment: @vini: checked, but still wondering: what is a defect?

Comment: These are fruit defects like bruises, rot, scald , hail etc

Comment: i think ill need to use connected component labeling to solve my problem

Comment: @vini Hmm, would it be correct to say that (so far) a defect is defined as simply a discoloration? That seems to be the only feature here ya?

Comment: Yes its just a discoloration however it gets seperated from the rest of the image which i have already achieved

Comment: I'm just thinking what this would do to strawberries. This might be very domain-specific. You could probably use a "similarity to known good pears/bananas/strawberries" measure that would be more robust, but that would deserve its own question. (Neural Network?)

Comment: Neural networks why not ! however formulating how it will be done and finding a solution would be tough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand what you call defects are detcted by changes in color of the fruit.

I would proceed as follow:

1. edge detection algorithm, (as you did), to detect the fruit region in the image.
2. In this region, compute the median color, that is the color that matches the most pixels (for example, it would be some kind of yellow for a banana)
3. For each  pixel in the fruit region, check the distant between the median computed at step 2 and the color of the pixel. If the distance is high, mark the pixel as defect
4. At the end, apply some morphological operator to remove outliers

Hope this helps.

Comment: Maybe add a connected component step in between to evaluate blobs further (on area size, mean distance of that blob to the mean color of the fruit, etc).